# Seleccionar una tabla u otra dependiendo de condición

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, table

Bien el problema es el siguiente

Tengo una tabla de USUARIOS que tiene un Cod_Usuario AUTOINCREMENTABLE y un campo Rol que indica el tipo de usuario que es.
Ese Cod_Usuario pasa como FOREIGN KEY a las tablas ADMINISTRADOR, DOCENTE, TUTOR

Al momento de cargar el sitio web, necesito extraer todos los datos de el usuario que ingresó, y solo tengo el Cod_Usuario como dato de entrada. Lo que necesito es saber como hacer un SELECT que, según el Cod_Usuario me extraiga los datos de Administrador O de Docente, O de tutor.

Estoy trabajando con PHP, y tranquilamente podría extraer el rol, usar una condicional IF, y según el rol hacer un SELECT diferente para cada Tabla(Admin, Docente, Tutor) , pero creo que no seria una buena practica. Por el momento estoy usando eso, pero quisiera cambiarlo.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que tu problema radica desde la normalizacion o el diseño de la base de datos, supongo que docence, tutor y administrador son los roles o permisos que tiene cada uno.

Lo que podrias hacer es hacer un sp dinamico dividido en secciones: @Seleccion (que es la sentencia select), @Origen (setencia from) y @Condicion (clausula web), dependiendo el valor de tu @cod_Usuario ejecutas las variables que arman la consulta.